# "splice() offset past end of array" en diferentes versiones de Perl

Tags: array, perl

Hoy, en mi trabajo, escribí algo así, en Perl:

```
my @x = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 );
splice(@x, 10);
```

y produjo el error:

> splice() offset past end of array at ./x line X.

Pero en mi laptop personal, no hay ningún error así. Ya sé que [es fácil suprimir el mensaje (en Inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346640/13860) con `no warnings 'misc';`, pero mi pregunta es:

¿Por qué la diferencia entre las versiones de Perl?

En el trabajo, veo el mensaje con Perl 5.14, y en mi equipo personal no lo veo con Perl 5.20.  ¿Cuando lo cambió, y por qué?

Comment: yo no manejo Perl pero quizas esto le ayude http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2013/04/msg201134.html creo que eso  ocurre entre la .14 y .16 en algunos sistemas https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=117729

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Como ya mencioné yo no uso Perl, pero mirando la documentación en una parte de ella dice lo siguiente:

> "Si el desplazamiento es más allá del final de la matriz, Perl emite
>   una advertencia, y (Perl) empalma/splice en el extremo de la matriz."

*...If OFFSET is past the end of the array, Perl issues a warning, and splices at the end of the array.*

De echo he revisado en varias versiones y es lo mismo por lo menos la documentación advierten sobre el *warning*.

Aquí le dejo los links (en Inglés);

- [Perl v 5.16.2](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.16.2/functions/splice.html)
- [Perl v 5.20.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.20.0/functions/splice.html)
- [Perl v 5.22](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)

Según lo anterior lo normal es el *warning*, pero por lo que se puede ver en el siguiente link, no en todas las versiones es así y también depende del OS.

http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2013/04/msg201134.html

Creo que eso ocurre entre la `5.14` y `5.16` en algunos sistemas, aquí puede ver la notificación de bug pero quizás también le suceda a usted en la `5.20` debido a su OS y no es que haya cambiado algo.

https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=117729

Comment: Tienes razón que la advertencia en este caso específico desapareció enter 5.14 y 5.16, y que esto fue una decisión  deliberada para quitarla y no un nuevo bug. La única razón que la versión del sistema operativo tiene algo que ver aquí es porque las personas que **no** instalan sus propio perls van a tener cualquier versión que les dé su OS.

Answer (score 9):

*voy a sumarme con la parte de la pregunta que no se ha respondido aun: **¿Por qué cambió?***

Cambio por que la intención de este código:

```
my @x = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 );
splice(@x, 3);
```

es claramente truncar el array si es demasiado largo y *no hay razon para emitir una advertencia si el array tiene **menos** elementos que el máximo especificado* (como en el caso citado en la pregunta)

[Fuente (en Inglés)](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commitdiff/5cd408a276e19848774860967c3ec06b67b863ee?hp=0890f1a536cff0aff68038cae78e02c9d9b6a2b2)